# How can I remove a corrupt AutoPlay option?

Tags: windows-7, autoplay

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CleanHandlers](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/autoplayhandlers.htm):

[image]

It works on Vista and 7 as well. If you wish to manually remove the registry entries, they are located in the following locations:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\Handlers\<handler>

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\EventHandlers\<Event Name></pre>
```